# magento 2.3 in live site css changes not taking it always taking old css which not exits

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, magento2.3.2, js-css

I am using magento 2.3.2 after development I have upload it in the live site and every thing was working perfectly then i hav installed mirasvit cache warmer in live then when ever i try to upload new css in live it not taking the the new changes.

I have tried by cleaning those file

- var/cache
- var/page_cache
- var/view_processed
- pub/static
- generated

then i have run **setup upgrade,compile,deploy,reindex,cache flush**
but nothing work

even if i delete pub static still old css working.in page view source it shows it coming from pub static but pub static is already blank

**And another thing is that in page view source it shows css in minify from but in admin it is not set as minify css**.

Please can any one suggest me what i should i do now.

Comment: have you tried clearing browser cache???

Answer (score 2):

First of all check via "**View Page Source**" in browser then check your respective file if it has all your recent changes.
After that try clearing these caches on "**Cache Management**" page
[image]

Comment: Thanks for response I have tried all this .new changes are not taking but it is in pub static file but not showing view page source.It shows css file when ever i have delete pub static file too. That's  mean in static file there is nothing exist physically but in in page source it shows  file comes from pub and if i click on it content is also showing but the does't exist in static file how can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Redis or Varnish is installed.

Try using this commands:

**Varnish** : `service varnish restart`

**Redis** : `redis-cli FLUSHALL`

Hope this will help You!!

Comment: no i dont have varnish or redis cache

Comment: But try this commands

Comment: my site is in developer mode but still it minify all the css and can't revert to normal mode again.